# unable to pass parameters as part of command in PHP script through AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpseclib

I am trying to pass start time and end time values from my front end screen to PHP script and trying to run a command with passed values of start time and end time in it using an AJAX call.

I am able to echo the start/end time on screen, but when i pass it as part of command in $ssh->exec (); I am not able to run it. Do you have any inputs as to why i cant pass as part of the command?

```
 $stime= $_POST['stime'];
 $etime = $_POST['etime'];

  echo $stime; // SUCCESS  ( 2015-07-27 16:32:23 )

  echo $ssh->exec('/tpo/umc/bin/monitoring_dump -n r02xy01 -m -t0 $stime -t1 $etime -f line> /tmp/adwant.txt');
```

AJAX CALL : 
$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('#button').click(function () {
        alert("first")
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://localhost:8182/ElitePass/login.php",
            data: {

                stime: $("#demo1").val()
                etime: $("#demo2").val()
            },

            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
                $('#resultip').html(data);
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert("Data sending failed");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any ajax

Comment: @developerwjk updated the query

Comment: Well, the problem isn't the ajax. Its `'` vs `"` but if you allow users to send input directly into a shell command you're asking to be majorly hacked, so you need to really rethink this.

Comment: @developerwjk where is the double quote error in the code?

Comment: In PHP `'$var'` outputs literally the string `$var`. `"$var"` outputs contents of `$var`

Comment: @developerwjk I am getting the correct output when i do echo $stime; - So $stime= $_POST['stime']; seems to be working fine. The problem is i am not able to replace it while passing it as part of command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE**

You should use double quotes instead of single quotes because variables like `'$stime'` don't get interpreted by PHP.

**SOLUTION**

See corrected code below:

```
echo $ssh->exec("/tpo/umc/bin/monitoring_dump -n r02xy01 -m -t0 $stime -t1 $etime -f line> /tmp/adwant.txt");
```

**NOTES**

However passing parameters to shell without validation is a **big security hole** and should be avoided.

You need to validate your `$stime` and `$etime` parameters to make sure they match the format (`2015-07-27 16:32:23`) that you expect.

For example:

```php
$is_stime_valid = preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/', $stime);
$is_etime_valid = preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/', $etime);

if($is_stime_valid and $is_etime_valid){
   echo $ssh->exec("/tpo/umc/bin/monitoring_dump -n r02xy01 -m -t0 $stime -t1 $etime -f line> /tmp/adwant.txt");
} else {
   # Error: invalid parameters
}
```